# What does the “column number” mean in code?

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I have always used the line number to debug. But in this article about Chrome Devtools, ["Go to a line number at a specific column"](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/05/go-to-a-line-number-at-a-specific-column),  I do not understand how the "column numbers" represent which position is meant.

Comment: "Column" means horizontal position on a line. The first character on a line is column 1, the second character is column 2, and so on.

Comment: @Jordan Thx ，got it